# Monotone and Dominated convergence Theorem implies L1-convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Dominated Convergence Theorem: Let $f_n$ be measurable and assume that $f_n$ converges a.e. to $f$. If $|f_n(x)|\leq g(x)$ for some integrable $g$ it follows that $f_n$ converges in $L^1$ to $f$, in particular $\int f_n\to\int f$.
Hence, we do not only have the convergence of the integrals but even $L^1$-convergence.

Now my question: Does the monotone convergence theorem also implies $L^1$ convergence or just  $\int f_n\to\int f$?

Comment: *Hint* $$\int_{\mathbb R}|f_n-f|=\int_{\mathbb R}f-\int_{\mathbb R}f_n.$$

Comment: So the answer must be yes since the right side converges to 0 by MCT. In the literature it is often noticed that DCT provide $L^1$-convergence, but never for MCT. So I thought that this will not hold in general.

Comment: The problem is that $\int f$ can by infinite. So, indeed MCT do not provide $L^1$ convergence. But if $\int f<\infty$, then $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.